# When are there two natural number $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sigma^{\circ m}(a_i)=g^{\circ n}(a_i)$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

Let us consider a Galois extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ by the roots $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$ of an irreducible polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x] $ of degree $5$. Thus the Galois group $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is a subgroup of $S_5$.

We know that any $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ permutes the roots $a_i, \ i=1,2,3,4,5$.

Let us consider another irreducible polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that it also permutes the elements $a_i, \ i=1,2,3,4,5$.

> When is there a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sigma(a_i)=g^{\circ n}(a_i)$ for all $i=1,2,3,4,5$ ?

> When are there two natural number $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sigma^{\circ m}(a_i)=g^{\circ n}(a_i)$ for all $i=1,2,3,4,5$ ?

---

For $n=1$, assume $\sigma$ is the cycle $(12345)$ and $g$ also permutes the elements $a_i$ in the same ordering i.e., $g(a_1)=a_2,~g(a_2)=a_3,~g(a_3)=a_4,~g(a_4)=a_5,~g(a_5)=a_1$ and hence $$\sigma(a_i)=g(a_i), \ \forall i=1,2,3,4,5$$

For $n=5=m$, we have $\sigma^{\circ 5}=\text{id}$ and we also have $$\sigma^{\circ 5}(a_i)=g^{\circ 5}(a_i), \ \forall i=1,2,3,4,5.$$
For the same $\sigma=(12345)$, for $n=m+5$, we have $$\sigma^{\circ n} (a_i)=g^{\circ (m+5)}(a_i), \ \forall i=1,2,3,4,5.$$
What are the other $\sigma,~g \in S_5$ doing my job ?

Is it possible to choose $\sigma$ and $g$ to be conjugate to each other doing my job ?

For example, if $\sigma=(12)(34)$ and $g=(23)(45)$, is it possible to answer my question ?

Any guidance please.

Comment: As you consider $g$ only as a map from the roots to the roots, i..e, as an element of the symmetric group of the roots. We can also canonically view the Galois groups as a subgroup of this permutation group. This way, your question rather boils down to arbitrary elements $\sigma, g$ of some symmetric group $S_n$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, yes. I am basically, then, looking two different $\sigma,~g \in S_n$ such that $\sigma(a_i)=g(a_i)$ for all $i=1,2,3,4,5$.

Comment: There's an ambiguity: in the very first sentence, what is of degree $5$? If you really mean the field, then later there are not going to be $\sigma=(123)$ are there?

Comment: But please can you confirm what you have written. You say that the polynomial $g$ permutes the roots of $f$. You mean that whenever you plug one of the $a_i$ into $g$ you get another root, yes?

Comment: @ancientmathematician, for your first comment, I mean $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $5$ or more. For your second comment, yes, $g$ permutes the roots of $f$. in other words $g(a_i) \in \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\}$ for all $i=1,2,3,4,5$

Comment: You've not answered my first comment. It is not about $g$ it is about $K$ and $f$. You seem to be saying both are degree $5$. Yet you later ask about a cycle of order $3$ in the GG of $K$. Can you clarify for me?

Comment: @ancientmathematician, to avoid confusion I have edited the question. We don't need to mention the degree of the $g(x)$ but we can think of it as a polynomial map that `permutes the 5 roots of f(x)`. Also as mention the Galois extension is $5$ degree extension. I hope there is no more confusion

Comment: How can you  have a an element $\sigma=(123)$ if the GG has order $5$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician, Thanks. I have edited the question

Comment: So the question is this: given a transitive subgroup $G$ of $S_5$ and an element $\sigma\in G$,  find for each $\tau\in G$ all $m,n$ such that $\sigma^m=\tau^n$. I can't think of anything except a tedious case-by-case analysis.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, Thanks. Note when $\sigma=g$, my question is answered. Now my question is$:$  whether or not there exists  two conjugates $\sigma,~ g \in G$ such that  $\sigma(a_i)=g(a_i), \ \forall i$, or $\sigma^m(a_i)=g^n(a_i), \ \forall i$ with a pair $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration described can only occur in two ways.

(I) The first possibility is that  $g(X)=X+q(X)f(X)$, and $g$ induces the identity permutation.

(II) The splitting field has degree $5$, the Galois group is cyclic, and $g$ induces a permutation which is either the identity or a power of $\sigma$.

To see this note that the minimal polynomial of each of the $a_i$ is by the irreducibility hypothesis $f(X)$.

Suppose that $g$ fixes one of the $a_i$: then $a_i$ is a root of $g(X)-X$, and so $f(X)|g(X)-X$. Then $g(a_j)=a_j$ for every $j$, and so $g$ induces the identity permutation. This is case (I).

Otherwise we have that $g$ induces a permutation without fixed points. So either $g$ induces a permutation $(abcde)$ or a permutation $(abc)(de)$. In the latter case $g\circ g$ induces a permutation of shape $(acb)(d)(e)$: but this has a fixed point and is not the identity, so by the previous argument cannot occur.

Hence $g$ induces a $5$-cycle. Hence each of $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_5$ can (by repeated composition of $g$) be expressed as a polynomial in $a_1$. That is, the splitting field $K$ is just $\mathbb{Q}[a_1]$, an extension field of degree $5$.

It remains to see that $g$ induces the same permutation as a power of $\sigma$. Without loss choose the notation so that $\sigma=(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5)$.

If $g(a_1)=a_2$ then applying $\sigma$ we have $g(a_2)=a_3$ and so on: that is $g$ induces $\sigma$.

If $g(a_1)=a_3$ then applying $\sigma$ we have $g(a_2)=a_4$, then $g(a_3)=a_5$, $g(a_4)=a_1$, $g(a_5)=a_2$: that is $g$ induces $\sigma^2$.

If $g(a_1)=a_4$ we get that $g$ induces $\sigma^3$; and if $g(a_1)=a_5$ we get that $g$ induces $\sigma^4$.

A final comment. If we are interested in explicit $g$ for case (II) note that they are all  going to be composition-powers of one which sends $a_1$ to $a_2$. There is (up to multiples of $f(X)$) at most one of these. And there certainly exists one, since $a_2\in\mathbb{Q}[a_1]$.